# intersection of the free form draw painterpath

Tags: qt, qpainter

im trying to make a free draw on the widget using the painterpath method . so in mouseMove event i  tried to find the intersection using 
qpainterPath.intersects(masterPainterPath)
[intersects](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainterpath.html#intersects-2)
but 
when i was moving inside the unclosed area or towards any point on the drawn path , the intersect of painterpath is returning true

**can you see the second image .. there even the endpoint (blue line) is not crossing the actual path .. but the painterpath intersect is returning true**

event the docs says 
***Set operations on paths will treat the paths as areas. Non-closed paths will be treated as implicitly closed***

the blue line represents the intersected line.

this is my code

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QLine>
#include <QDebug>


class MousePaintWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
    explicit MousePaintWidget(QWidget * parent = 0)
        : QWidget(parent)
        , mousePressed(false)
    {
        ;
    }

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
    {
        QPainter p(this);
        p.drawPath(masterPath);

        if(mousePressed)
        {
            p.setPen(Qt::red);
            QLineF line = QLineF(firstPoint, lastPoint);
            p.drawLine(line);

        }

        p.setPen(QPen(Qt::blue,4));
        p.drawPath(newerPath);
    }

    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * mouseEvent)
    {
        if(mousePressed)
        {
            QPainterPath newPath;
            newPath.moveTo(lastPoint);
            newPath.lineTo(mouseEvent->pos());

            if(masterPath.elementCount() == 0)
            {
                masterPath.moveTo(lastPoint);
            }
            else
            {
                if(newPath.intersects(masterPath))
                {
                    newerPath.moveTo(lastPoint);
                    newerPath.lineTo(mouseEvent->pos());
                    //                    mousePressed = false;
                    masterPath.lineTo(lastPoint);
                }
                else
                {
                    masterPath.lineTo(lastPoint);
                }
            }
            lastPoint = mouseEvent->pos();
            update();
        }
    }

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * mouseEvent)
    {
        firstPoint = lastPoint = mouseEvent->pos();
        masterPath = QPainterPath();
        mousePressed = true;
    }

    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *)
    {
        mousePressed = false;
    }

private:
    bool            mousePressed;
    QPainterPath    masterPath;
    QPoint          lastPoint;
    QPoint          firstPoint;
    QPainterPath newerPath;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MousePaintWidget w;
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

and i have attached the normal condition and the one which i have the problem with it.

[image: Normal drawn free draw]

[image: When i move towrds any point of the painterpath]

> the debug message after the intersection happened  The complete points
>   on the master list is: QPolygonF(QPointF(422, 141) QPointF(423, 140)
>   QPointF(425, 139) QPointF(427, 139) QPointF(428, 139) QPointF(429,
>   138) QPointF(431, 137) QPointF(433, 136) QPointF(436, 136)
>   QPointF(437, 135) QPointF(440, 135) QPointF(442, 134) QPointF(444,
>   134) QPointF(446, 133) QPointF(448, 133) QPointF(450, 133)
>   QPointF(451, 133) QPointF(452, 133) QPointF(455, 133) QPointF(456,
>   133) QPointF(457, 133) QPointF(459, 133) QPointF(460, 133)
>   QPointF(461, 133) QPointF(463, 133) QPointF(464, 134) QPointF(465,
>   134) QPointF(466, 134) QPointF(467, 134) QPointF(469, 135)
>   QPointF(469, 136) QPointF(470, 136) QPointF(471, 136) QPointF(472,
>   137) QPointF(473, 138) QPointF(474, 139) QPointF(475, 139)
>   QPointF(475, 140) QPointF(475, 142) QPointF(475, 143) QPointF(475,
>   144) QPointF(475, 145) QPointF(475, 146) QPointF(474, 146)
>   QPointF(474, 147) QPointF(473, 148) QPointF(472, 149) QPointF(471,
>   151) QPointF(470, 151) QPointF(470, 152) QPointF(469, 152)
>   QPointF(469, 153) QPointF(468, 154) QPointF(467, 154) QPointF(467,
>   155) QPointF(466, 155) QPointF(465, 155) QPointF(464, 155)
>   QPointF(422, 141) ) 
>   -------------------------------------------------------  The complete points on the poly: QPolygonF(QPointF(463, 155) QPointF(463, 154)
>   QPointF(463, 155) )

Comment: it is hard to follow what you are trying to do, even with the images. Edit your first paragraph to make it more understandable.

Comment: can you see the second image .. there even the endpoint (blue line) is not  crossing the actual path .. but the painterpath intersect is returning true.

Comment: May be that's because the starting point of new path intersects the last point of master path. Check if they are connected, then do not consider them as intersected.

Comment: i have posted the debug messages of starting and end point details of the paths.

Answer (score 1):

```
newPath.intersects(masterPath)
```

**is always true because it is the case**.

[image: annotated repost]

Rather than using `newPath.intersects(masterPath)` compute the intersection  path and remove the first end point from that path. Then test if the path is empty.

Something like

```
interPath = newPath.intersected (masterPath );
interPath -= QPainterPath(lastPoint); //test first without this line
if(interPath.empty())
{
...
}
```

For a practical solution you need a small margin of error. You should create a small circle path around the beginning of `newPath` instead of a `QPainterPath(lastPoint)`;

Comment: thanks UmNyobe . im trying your method of computing the intersect path .i will update my result

Comment: QRectF rect2(newPath.currentPosition().x(),newPath.currentPosition().y(), 2, 2);
newPath.addRect(rect2); it returns in the same way like the QPainterPath::intersects(). returning false like my previous implementation